# Python C module memory leak

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, memory-leaks, bitmap

I have a C library adapted for python, it is part of the project rdpy(https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy).
However, there is a memory leak, that I cant kill in python code: deleting references to objects (input=None, output=None), gc.collect(), etc. Leaks analyzers, such as pympler, also dont show objects that occupy memory. I also found that the same code is used in the rdesktop project (https://github.com/rdesktop/rdesktop/blob/master/bitmap.c), but it works correctly there, maybe it's a matter of integration with python. What in this function can make leak a memory?

```
/* Specific rename for RDPY integration */
#define uint8   unsigned char
#define uint16  unsigned short
#define unimpl(str, code)

#define  RD_BOOL    int
#define False   0
#define True    1
/* end specific rename */

......................................

static PyObject*
bitmap_decompress_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    Py_buffer output, input;
    int width = 0, height = 0, bpp = 0;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s*iis*i", &output, &width, &height, &input, &bpp))
        return NULL;

    if(bitmap_decompress((uint8*)output.buf, width, height, (uint8*)input.buf, input.len, bpp) == False)
        return NULL;

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef rle_methods[] =
{
     {"bitmap_decompress", bitmap_decompress_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, "decompress bitmap from microsoft rle algorithm."},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initrle(void)
{
     (void) Py_InitModule("rle", rle_methods);
}
```